# Passing parameters to resource using embedded Jetty

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jetty, inversion-of-control

I have a resource I want to expose that has a constructor with parameters for injection. However I'm not using any injection framework, and I've got Jetty embedded.

Right now Jetty scans for Resources with this:

```
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/server");
ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.to.scan");
servletContextHandler.addServlet(jerseyServletHolder, "/*");
```

But it prevents me from injecting anything in the constructor, so I have to use a default constructor.

I'd like to specify my own instance to pass to my resource constructor. Is there a way to instantiate the resource manually and add it to the servlet container?

Is it possible to do something like this :

```
MyRestResource resource = new MyRestResource(param1, param2);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(resource);
```

or something like that?

Comment: Your question title, and your question contents are for 2 different things.  The title asks for how to pass information into a servlet.  While your content asks how to make MyRestResource behave like a servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyRestResource` is a `Servlet`, then you can use the [existing servlet holder constructor](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHolder.html#ServletHolder%28javax.servlet.Servlet%29).

```java
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/server");
ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.to.scan");
servletContextHandler.addServlet(jerseyServletHolder, "/*");
MyRestResource resource = new MyRestResource(param1, param2);
// wrap resource in a ServletHolder
ServletHolder resourceHolder = new ServletHolder(resource);
// assign resource to a Servlet pathSpec
servletContextHandler.addServlet(resourceHolder, "/rest");
```

If you have a servlet, and want to access something setup at startup time, use the [ContextHandler.setAttribute(String, Object)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [ServletContext.getAttribute(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) techniques.

In your server startup

```java
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/server");
ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.to.scan");
servletContextHandler.addServlet(jerseyServletHolder, "/*");
MyRestResource resource = new MyRestResource(param1, param2);
// Set resource as a context attribute
servletContextHandler.setAttribute("rest-1", resource);
```

Then access is later from the servlet api

```java
ServletContext ctx = servletRequest.getServletContext();
MyRestResource resource = (MyRestResource) ctx.getAttribute("rest-1");
```

Comment: What if MyRestResource doesn't extend Servlet? I'm only using Jersey annotation (or javax annotations) like "@Path", "@Produces", "@Consumes", etc, before MyRestResource class. Would it be logical to just extend Servlet?

Comment: If it doesn't extend Servlet, then it is likely meant to be managed by Jersey.  Using Jetty's ServletContextHandler with that kind of object is not possible.  At this point you will need to focus on making it work with Jersey and its mechanisms.

Comment: It seems that the link provided is dead

Comment: @rpax that's because Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life) now, replace `stable-8` with `stable-9` to see the up to date documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You can inject dependencies into Jersey resources by registering a (Jersey) ServletContainer with a customized ResourceConfig. Please have a look at the code below as an example of creating a TimeResource class with a clock injected into it via a constructor.

```
public void start() {
    server = new Server(6666);
    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
    handler.setContextPath("");
    // adds Jersey Servlet with a customized ResourceConfig
    handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig())), "/*");
    server.setHandler(handler);
    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not start the server", e);
    }
}

private ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {
    // manually injecting dependencies (clock) to Jersey resource classes
    return new ResourceConfig().register(new TimeResource(clock));
}
```

A full example with source code is available under:

http://unclejamal.github.io/2013/09/18/manual-dependency-injection-with-jersey-and-embedded-jetty.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.